# Rearrange and solve for $N: 16 = \frac{1}{n}\cdot 25 + \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot 218.75$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, finance

I need to solve for $N$ to get $16$ with the following formula, I'm very bad a re-arranging though, so does anyone have an answer to this?

$$16 = \frac 1 n \cdot 25 + \frac{n-1} n \cdot218.75$$

Would be great if you can help!

**Remark**

The question is about portfolio theory and the formula is as follow:

Portfolio variance $= \frac 1n \times $ asset standard deviation $+ \frac{n-1}{n}\times $ asset covariance.

In my case,

Asset standard deviation $= 25$,

Asset covariance $= 218.75$

So for example with $N=2$, portfolio variance $= 20.53$; with $N=20$, portfolio variance $= 15.46$

Could you tell me how to rearrange this now?

Comment: what do you mean by $$n-1/1$$?

Comment: Well I try to calculate the number of assets (N) I need to restrict the portfolio variance to 16%. That's what the formula stands for.

Comment: Where you wrote $(n-1/1)$ did you actually mean $(n-1)/1$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped it. It needs to be (n-1)/n, I have now revised this. Could you help me to rearrange the formula above to solve for N with a max. "Portfolio Variance" of 16?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying through by $n$ gives
$$
16n=25+218.75n-218.75 \\
\Rightarrow 193.75=202.75n \\
\Rightarrow n=\frac{193.75}{202.75}.
$$